# Doctrine it returns an empty array

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have run into an issue in Doctrine. I have built the following query with queryBuilder:

```
$queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
                             ->select('a')
                             ->join('a.map', 'm');
$critery = $request->query->get('criteria_map_name');
$queryBuilder->where('m.name LIKE :criteria_map_name');
$queryBuilder->setParameter('criteria_map_name', '%'.$critery.'%');
```

Here is the query that is logged prior to execution:

```
SELECT 
  s0_.id AS id0, 
  ....
  s0_.modifications_id AS modifications_id44 
FROM 
  server s0_ 
  INNER JOIN map m1_ ON s0_.mapId = m1_.id 
WHERE 
  m1_.name LIKE ?
```

Parameters: ['%de%']

When I execute this query (after inserting the parameters seen above) directly in MySQL it works perfectly, returning the results.

However, when it is executed by Doctrine it returns an empty array.

Comment: but if I execute this query:
SELECT * FROM server s
INNER JOIN map m ON s.map_id = m.id
WHERE 1

mysql returned result
Any ideas?

Comment: "INNER JOIN map m1_ ON s0_.mapId = m1_.id", have you put camel case instead of underscores in your entity mapping definitions? (mapId instead of map_id).

Comment: How do you get the results from the query builder?

Comment: @dan-belden , `/**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="map_id", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $mapId;`

Comment: `$dql = 'SELECT a FROM GameServerBundle:Server\Server a
                    INNER JOIN a.map m';

            $query = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()->createQuery($dql)->getResult();`

Empty result

$dql = 'SELECT a FROM GameServerBundle:Server\Server a';

            $query = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()->createQuery($dql)->getResult();

Not empty

Comment: Hey Daniel, can you edit your question and add in your server and map entity definitions, preferably with the full retrieval block answering the question above. The above mapping you have commented is for a mapId property, which is not what you have asked doctrine to join on "map". This looks to me like you have not defined your entity relationship between the two entites you are joining rather than the retrieval approach.